# Ich nehme die Jacke ab und ich lege die Jacke ab?

Tags: standard-german

Kann ich sagen "Ich nehme die Jacke ab", anstatt "ich lege die Jacke ab"?

Ich habe in einem Buch gelesen, dass man so sagt: "ich nehme die Jacke ab". Aber einige Freunde von mir sagten, das Verb klingt in diesem Fall ungewöhnlich und wird nicht benutzt.

Wann kann ich "abnehmen" für Kleidungsstück verwenden?

Comment: Darf ich Ihnen den Mantel abnehmen? = May I take your coat?

Comment: Danke dir! Aber wenn ich meine, dass ich meinen Mantel ablege...kann ich auch abnehmen nutzen

Comment: Nein. Aber Du kannst Deinen Hut abnehmen.

Answer (score 6):

*Abnehmen* (man beachte die Vorsilbe **ab**) wird nur für kleine Teile verwendet, die **auf** etwas  sitzen, beispielsweise der Hut, der auf dem Kopf sitzt, oder die Brille, die auf der Nase sitzt.

Das Verb, das für Kleidung immer funktioniert, ist *ausziehen*: Schuhe, Handschuhe, Pullover, Mantel, Hemd. Das beschreibt aber nicht, was man dann mit dem ausgezogenen Kleidungsstück macht, *ablegen* im Sinne von *hinlegen* ist da eine der Möglichkeiten.

Es gibt aber noch die breitere Bedeutung von *ablegen*, Gegenstände loszuwerden, weil man z. B. in einen Innenraum tritt, vergleiche [DWDS, Bedeutung 1](https://www.dwds.de/wb/ablegen), die auch für Stöcke, Schirme und Handtaschen verwendet wird.

Comment: vielen lieben Dank! es fällt mir nach 10 Jahren Lernen immer noch schwer, ein richtiges übliches Wort zu finden. Und immer wieder Muttersprachler fragen. Hast du einen Tipp, wie ich noch double check machen kann. hehe

Answer (score 5):

Zunächst eine kleine Klarstellung: "ablegen" bedeutet, sich eines Kleidungsstücks zu entledigen, das man angezogen hatte. Man kann sich Mäntel, Socken, Westen, Jacken, ... *anziehen* - und sie danach wieder *ablegen*.

"Abnehmen" hingegen hat mehrere Bedeutungen: die hier wichtigste ist, etwas aus der Obhut (real oder im übertragenen Sinne) jemandes anderen in die eigene Verantwortung zu transferieren. Man kann jemandem eine Tätigkeit abnehmen (sie statt seiner durchführen), Verantwortung abnehmen (ihn aus der Verantwortung entlassen), Geld abnehmen (ihn um dasselbe erleichtern), aber man kann auch jemandem ein Kleidungsstück abnehmen.

Letzteres wird üblicherweise entweder von Bediensteten als Teil ihrer Dienstleistung getan (z.B. vom Kellner in einem Restaurant, der Gästen die Mäntel abnimmt, um sie in die Garderobe zu verfrachten) oder als Akt der Höflichkeit (Herren nehmen Damen, wenn die sich des Mantels, der Jacke oder dgl. entledigen, dieselben ab und bringen sie an einen geeigneten Aufbewahrungsort - Garderobe, etc.). Analoges gilt für Accessoires wie Schirme und dgl. mehr.

Mit anderen Worten: im Sinne von "ausziehen" kann man Kleidungsstücke nur *ablegen*, nicht *abnehmen*. Abnehmen kann man sie nur anderen, die sie zuvor abgelegt haben.

Dabei gibt es allerdings eine Ausnahme: Hüte kann man abnehmen - sowohl anderen, wenn die ihn vorher abgenommen (oder abgelegt - auch möglich) haben, aber auch den eigenen, was dann bedeutet, ihn vom Kopf zu entfernen. Was der Grund für diese Ausnahme ist, ist mir nicht bekannt, aber ich vermute, daß es damit zu tun hat, daß das "Ausziehen" eines Hutes mit deutlich weniger "Ausziehungsaufwand" verbunden ist als das Ausziehen anderer Kleidungsstücke, die aufwendiger vom Körper zu entfernen sind.

Answer (score 0):

I would say "Ich nehme die Jacke ab." and too "Ich nehme den Mantel ab." This means to undress. "Ich lege die Jacke ab." means that I undress and I put it down somewhere (I don't hang it).
However, I would rather say "Ich ziehe die Jacke aus."

The word "ablegen" is very old-fashioned in that context. It stems from a time, when men were carrying walking sticks and women were carrying umbrellas, so they really had to "lie down" them somewhere. From that times stems the request "Bitte abzulegen!" as a polite expression for "Please undress your coat."

You always would say "Ich nehme den Hut ab." for a hat, because you really have to take it down.

Answer (score -1):

Man kann auch einen Silikonabdruck von einem Körperteil abnehmen oder dem genesenen Unfallopfer den Gips. Oft nimmt dann aber ein Zweiter das Objekt um damit etwas zu tun (Jacke aufhängen, Handschuhe ablegen, Gips entsorgen; die Silikonform überlassen wir der Phantasie des Lesers).

Man würde jedoch auch sagen können "Ich habe mir selbst den Gips abgenommen."

Für mich klingt es plausibel zu sagen, "Nehmen Sie bitte die Mäntel ab - wir gehen jetzt durch das heiße Tropenhaus des botanischen Gartens.", wenn von einem Ablegen auf eine Bank oder dgl. nicht die Rede sein kann. Man zieht das Kleidungsstück aus aber behält es in Hand oder Arm.